# Return list of models passing in a List of ids using repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm using the repository with the Unit of work pattern based on:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Their Get function looks like:

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
```

Now I want to get a List of rows as an output.

The query will also have a WHERE IN clause like:

```
SELEcT *
FROM ...
   INNER JOIN ...
WHERE homeId in (select homeId ....)
```

I have the list of home ids:

```
List<int> homeIdList = ...
```

How can I build this query using the Get method above?

```
Get(x => x.Id == cityId, includeProperties: "CityBlock, CityBlock.Homes")
```

The above is a query that is similiar to what I want, but I want to limit the Homes to be where their id is in the List homeIdList.

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use List's `Contains` method which will is translated to sql's `in` operator.
I Suggest that you try to get a list of Homes with their `CityBlock` and `City` property included, then you can use linq to get all cities:

```
var repository = new GenericRepository<Home>();
var homes = repository.Get(home => homeIdList.Contains(home.Id), 
                            includeProperties: "CityBlock, CityBlock.City")
                            .ToList();
var cities = homes.Select(h => h.CityBlock.City).Distinct().ToList();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but b/c of lazy loading it will fetch the others right? so this won't do what I want...

Comment: @user1361315 I'm not sure that I understood you comment, but this `GenericRepositoy` fetches navigation properties eagerly, thus you don't need lazy loading (that's why we specify `includeProperties:...`)